# Android dumpsys meminfo - unknown field

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, adb

I am trying to solve some leaks in my Android application.
When on Android Studio, the memory usage returns me <10 MB allocated.
When I look on the tablet application manager, I can see my application is using about 180MB.

I have then used Eclipse memory analyzer. But it also doesn't report a such usage of memory.

I then tried to understand `dumpsys meminfo`.
I can see most of the memory usage goes into `Unknown` part of the array displayed (see image below).

Can anyone please tell me what is this `Unknown` part. Also if anyone have an idea of where the leak can come from looking at the application `dumpsys meminfo`.

Cheers

[image: Application dumpsys]

Comment: Same problem.I am profiling a cordova app on android device

Comment: were you ever able to find out what's causing this issue?